# When exactly does postfix unary operator happen?

Tags: java, operators, unary-operator

I read a few post regarding unary operator:
[What is the Difference between postfix and unary and additive in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182477/what-is-the-difference-between-postfix-and-unary-and-additive-in-java)
["C - C++" joke about postfix/prefix operation ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227963/c-c-joke-about-postfix-prefix-operation-ordering)

And a few more.

However, I still don't understand *exactly* when the value is changed.

For example:

```
int x = 1;
x = x++;
System.out.print("x = x++ ==> ");
System.out.print(" x = " + x);
System.out.println();
```

---

```
int x = 1;
x = x++ + x++;
System.out.print("x = x++ + x++ ==> ");
System.out.print(" x = " + x);
System.out.println();
```

The output is:

```
x = x++ ==>  x = 1
x = x++ + x++ ==>  x = 3
```

So in the first block `x` is assigned to `x` and afterwards incremented, but the value is never used, otherwise the output would have been `x = 2`.

In the second block, if I understand correctly, the first `x++` is evaluated before the assignment and the second `x++` is evaluated afterwards but is never used.

If in the second block both `x++` would have been evaluated after the assignment but never used, the output would have been `x = 2`. If both have been used, the output would have been `x = 4`.

My IDE also indicated that the first `x++` is used, but the second is not used:
[image]

So to conclude - I'm still confused about when and how *exactly* the increment is done.

Comment: You should read [What is x after “x = x++”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x).

Comment: @AndyTurner I read it. Didn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the line

```
x = x++ + x++;
```

Assuming `x = 1`, the first `x++` returns "1" as the value, and *then* it increments `x` to 2. So basically, it's assigning the old value back to `x`.

The second `x++` does the same; it returns the value of `x`, which is now 2, and only then increments its value to 3 - that value, is not used.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
tmp = x;
x = x + 1;

tmp2 = x;
x = x + 1; // not used

x = tmp + tmp2;
```

Links that may help you:

- [JSL - 15.14.2. Postfix Increment Operator ++](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)
- [JLS - 15.15.1. Prefix Increment Operator ++](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1)
- [What is x after “x = x++”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911776/what-is-x-after-x-x)